# What can I do to pay off Summer Tuition balance?

Tags: student-loan, college, debt-restructuring

My financial situation breaks down like this. I currently have 3 semesters to graduation but I have a hold preventing me from taking classes because I owe a balance for tuition totaling in $4,114.74. I took this semester off and have been working 3 jobs sending payments every week. Now I owe $1500. I doubt I will have it paid in full in time to register for classes this winter so I am considering a private student loan through discover. Is there any other avenue that I can use to pay this off? I really don't want more student loan debt, but I also can't afford more time off school.

Answer (score 4):

Would any of your current employers consider giving you an advance?  Do you have things to sell?  Have you attempted to talk to the office and asking for a little grace given the progress you have made?

Aside from that the best course of action might be take another semester off.  This way you can continue to work like a dog and have your next semester(s) saved.  After all what is going to prevent you from being right back in the same boat?

Can you earn enough, by taking one semester off, to pay off the loan and save enough for the other three semesters?  That would be my goal.

Comment: I sold all of my video games, and my old bike. I did and they put in a payment plan that would keep me from going to collections and taking a credit-crotch punch. I should see if there is anyway I can enroll now though. Your right, continuing to work would be possible I am also looking at joining the army and I have $10 dispersed in penny stocks hoping to gain something there. It would be impossible to save for that many semesters as the jobs I work aren't steady. 2 have hours that fluctuate and shrink with the semester and the other is a co-op that I wont have after Christmas.

Comment: That $10 in penny stocks is pretty much lost.  Next time you feel the urge just set a $10 bill on fire.

Comment: I am desperate and thought it'd be a good idea, so far I've made a net of about .30 cents. But it's alot of work since they fluctuate so fast. I do not have enough money to go into the real stock market. Do you have any advice? Aside from avoiding penny stocks?

Comment: Manipulating numbers isn't going to do it. You need more real income, or you need a loan. The student aid office may be able to help you arrange a loan.